# PayPal amount value issue

Tags: paypal

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="5 day package">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.00">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

I Have this code. When it takes me to PayPal page I get the item_name value
I get the quanity value,
But I dont get the amount I get 0.
Was reading paypal docs but didnt found anything usefull.

If any suggestions?

Comment: you for got to put your email in hidden field! https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

Comment: Still the same problem
I just get 5 Package and amount 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

```
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="herschelgomez@xyzzyu.com">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12oz Bottle">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```